# Module not found: Error: can't resolve the component. Facing issue when trying to import component from a package made using ng-packagr

Tags: angular, typescript, ng-packagr

**Description**
I have exported the package from a different app and trying to use that package in a different application as a dependency. I am getting the following error when trying to import components from that package.

```
  ERROR in ./src/app/core/component-dynamic-loader/component-dynamic-loader.component.ts
  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'avanade-packagr/src/app/modules/xd-components/xd-list-view/xd-list-view.component'
```

in 'C:\Users\aditi.malviya\work\xd.ng.starter.demo.app\src\app\core\component-dynamic-loader'

**How To Reproduce**
**index.ts:**

```
 export * from './xd-components.module';
```

**public_api.ts:**

```
 export * from './src/app/modules/xd-components/index';
```

**ng-package.json:**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "lib": {
  "entryFile": "public_api.ts"
},
  "externals": {
  "moment": "moment",
  "lodash": "lodash"
  }
}
```

**import statement**:

```
  import { XdListViewComponent } from 'avanade-packagr/src/app/modules/xd- 
  components/xd-list-view/xd-list-view.component';
```

Comment: What is the library name you had given for `xd-components.module` ?

Comment: @SunilSingh xd-components.module is the module name just like app.module.ts. So in the index.ts file, I am trying to export everything from the xd-components module.

Comment: ng-packagr has issues with barrelling. Remove index.ts file and import directly. It might work. Here is the barrelling issue: https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/567